# ClosedXML and UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, closedxml

I'm currently working on an app for my company, where I have to load Excel data transform it (e.g. doing calculations based on rules) and export it back to Excel and format that document.

I've chosen to develop the app in UWP (mainly because the layout is much nicer than WinForms, databinding is an awesome feature, etc.)

The problem, though, is reading the Excel files. My previous version of the app (in WinForms) used the Office.Interop COM library. But that is not supported in UWP (found out that the hard way...). I am aware of the fact that you could sideload or bridge an application that handles that, but I figured that moving to OpenXML, which also provides better performance, would be a better solution.

Working with OpenXML is, though, a bit of a pain. So I found this beautiful wrapper, ClosedXML. However, when I try to read an Excel file. I get this error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
>   'ClosedXML.Excel.XLHelper' threw an exception.'
>
> PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Drawing is not supported on this
>   platform.

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
wb.AddWorksheet("Text");
wb.SaveAs(@"\\...\Text.xlsx");
```

Okay, well that makes perfectly sense. So I started looking on the web for any solution. [Multi-targeting: net40, net461, netstandard2.0](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/101), is what I came up with. I updated a couple of packages and so on, but the issue persists. Now I start wondering if it's possible at all...

Does someone has more info about the compatibility between UWP and ClosedXML? And how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is unfortunately not possible to fix, because the library uses `System.Drawing` APIs within its code, which are not implemented on UWP. This is a unfortunate quirk of the .NET Standard support - a platform can declare it supports .NET Standard X.Y but may not actually support it completely and may throw the not implemented exception instead. Unfortunately, the only way to make ClosedXML work on UWP is to [raise an issue](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues) to the team and ask them to find a way to work around the missing APIs on UWP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried a couple of other things (including downloading the ClosedXML source code and deleting some parts where System.Drawing was used, however, System.Drawing appeared to be used all over the library, unfortunately...). Do you have any suggestions how I would still be able to edit Excel files on UWP platform? It's a shame that this it made so difficult...

Comment: I think OpenXML is the best option for you. Alternatively you could look into Syncfusion's solution - https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio , but that is paid unless you are egligible to a community license I think

Comment: My company would not, so that one is probably out of the question... I'll dive into OpenXML then. Unfortunately it is much more confusing than Office.Interop... Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Hope you will find a way to make it work :-). In case this solves your question, please make the answer as solution so that it is resolved. Happy coding!

Comment: Maybe I do have one more question: I've read that sideloading an app would make it possible to run Interop COM libraries, however, this process is very clunky and not well documented. Do you happen to know any other solution to run Interop COM from an UWP app without the sideloading hassle? If not, that's fine too. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I am thinking the you could use a full trust process that would be a classic. NET Framework app that could use the ClosedXML library or any other approach for that matter, but you would have to state the reasons for this in the submission of the app to the Store and may be more complex in the end. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher

Comment: The app would just be an internal company app, so it doesn't have to be submitted to the Store. That would be no problem. I will look into that. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: There are some samples using this approach in the UWP samples gallery. It might be the best solution for you :-)

Comment: Instead of UWP, why not just use WPF + MVVM for the data binding? That way your app will run on the full dotnet framework and you won't have any restrictions with ClosedXML.